# Applescript : Clipboard and date

Tags: date, applescript, icalendar

In applescript, I can copy date from a Numbers Sheet.

When I try to past it as a "start date" in an iCal Event, it doesn't work.

Here is what is working :

```
set start_date to date ("2 juin 2014")
set end_date to date ("3 juin 2014")

tell calendar "Cal"
    make new event at end with properties {summary:"Chris", start date:start_date, end date:end_date}
end tell
```

Here is what is NOT working (supposing the clipboard is "2 juin 2014")

```
set dateString to the clipboard as text

set start_date to date (dateString)
set end_date to date ("3 juin 2014")

tell calendar "Cal"
   make new event at end with properties {summary:"Chris", start date:start_date, end date:end_date}
end tell
```

Thanks for your answers

Dam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the date creation outside of the app tell block.You did not show the

```
tell app "Calendar"
```

portion of your code (please do so in the future) to illustrate the problem, but it looks like that's your conflict. Working code looks like this:

```
set dateString to the clipboard as Unicode text  -- "22 Juin 2014"
set start_date to date (dateString)
set end_date to date ("23 Juin 2014")

tell application "Calendar"
    tell calendar "Cal"
        make new event at end with properties {summary:"Chris", start date:start_date, end date:end_date}
    end tell
end tell
```

It's a good practice to not put things inside an app's tell block that don't need to be there.